# Android - Outgoing transactions from this process must be FLAG_ONEWAY

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, motorola

I'm facing two issues when running my Android application on Moto G6 device (on another devices or emulator there is no such problem). In my app, there is a simple LoginActivity that after successful login starts MainActivity (in onPostExecute of AsyncTask):

```
val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

However on Moto G6 (not happening on Sony Xperia), there is an error that transaction should be ONEWAY:

```
10-17 07:50:45.058 1878-2153/? W/Binder: Outgoing transactions from this process must be FLAG_ONEWAY
java.lang.Throwable
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:736)
    at android.app.assist.AssistStructure$ParcelTransferReader.fetchData(AssistStructure.java:407)
    at android.app.assist.AssistStructure$ParcelTransferReader.go(AssistStructure.java:343)
    at android.app.assist.AssistStructure.ensureData(AssistStructure.java:2110)
    at com.android.server.autofill.Session$1.send(Session.java:200)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.reportAssistContextExtras(ActivityManagerService.java:13475)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2467)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3082)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674)
```

Any suggestion or help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem.
Have you managed to solve it?

Comment: I've encountered the same error on Pixel Android emulator (API level 27)

Comment: nope, cleaning project did not help :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For functional purposes, this is just a warning that inter-process (via binder) call is blocking, [AOSP source for this warning](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/BinderProxy.java;l=512?q=%22Outgoing%20transactions%20from%20this%20process%20must%20be%22).

By default, inter-process calls are blocking but when it is marked `oneway` (via AIDL), it's executed as fire & forget (non-blocking). It is important for system processes to use non-blocking calls when calling into other (potentially unknown user code) to avoid stalling the whole system. So this warning is meant to flag dangerous calls like this: see [android developer AIDL documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl) regarding `oneway`.

In this example, there is a call into `ActivityManagerService` `reportAssistContextExtras` (AM runs in primary system process), which in turn invokes another IPC (inter-process) call `AssistStructure$ParcelTransferReader.fetchData`, and the latter is not marked `oneway` (which triggers this warning).

> on Moto G6 (not happening on Sony Xperia)

They might have different implementation/android versions or different call sequence (so it's not invoked)..

Bottom line, it's android implementation oversight; might be already resolved for this particular case, see latest [source of activity manager](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/wm/ActivityTaskManagerService.java;l=3182?q=reportAssistContextExtras) .

If doesn't create functional problems, ignore the warning if it's not relevant to your code. If such call (`fetchData` in this example) resolves to your code, ensure not to block (return quickly).

However, it might lead to system watchdog kill, search for other logs to understand the consequences, like:

```
W Watchdog: *** WATCHDOG KILLING SYSTEM PROCESS: Blocked in handler on main thread (main)
W Watchdog: main annotated stack trace:
W Watchdog:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
```

Ultimately, it might need to be filed with Google if it's not your code..

Answer (score -1):

I had this without reason. turn off instant run if it is on. Clean project (a few times if one is not anough) and rebuild the project

Answer (score -1):

**File | Invalidate Caches/Restart**  worked for me